# Display bug between dash ( - ) and underscore ( _ )?

Tags: bug, comments, global-inbox

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759116/i-want-to-rename-column-name-in-sql-server) seemed to ask about a NOOP (renaming a table column named `car_no` into `car_no`).

When OP [commented under my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/27654039?noredirect=1), my inbox showed the comment text like this:

[image]

Please note the dashed `[car-no]` and the underscored `car_no`.

On the question page, it looks like this:

[image]

Where the dash is displayed as an underscore.

The other repliers seemed to see the same thing as I did, as they answered the same way.

Is there a bug here ? Or is there another reason ?

Comment: Well, they edited the comment...presumably the inbox message just doesn't reflect the update.

Comment: Oh... That would mean the real question comes from the OP thinks the brackets are part of the column name, right ?

Comment: Ok. Answer edited. Thanks!